# Google Cloud SQL Performance

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm surprised by the poor performance of Google Cloud SQL when I ran a sysbench on it. Here's the result from sysbench after setting the test run from these 2 commands.

```
sysbench --test=oltp --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-host=173.194.225.xxx --mysql-db=test --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=MYPASSWORD prepare

sysbench --test=oltp --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-host=173.194.225.xxx --mysql-db=test --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=96220751 --max-time=60 --oltp-read-only=on --max-requests=0 --num-threads=8 run
```

Sysbench Result:

```
OLTP test statistics:
queries performed:
    read:                            7756
    write:                           0
    other:                           1108
    total:                           8864
transactions:                        554    (9.13 per sec.)
deadlocks:                           0      (0.00 per sec.)
read/write requests:                 7756   (127.83 per sec.)
other operations:                    1108   (18.26 per sec.)

Test execution summary:
total time:                          60.6740s
total number of events:              554
total time taken by event execution: 484.0527
per-request statistics:
     min:                                856.76ms
     avg:                                873.74ms
     max:                                897.26ms
     approx.  95 percentile:             890.33ms

Threads fairness:
events (avg/stddev):           69.2500/0.66
execution time (avg/stddev):   60.5066/0.21
```

Can anyone comment on this result? I ran the test with D0 and D4 and I'm getting very similar result. Even the sysbench test from [digitalocean](http://digitalocean.com) shows a far better performance as shown below:

```
OLTP test statistics:
queries performed:
    read:                            358498
    write:                           0
    other:                           51214
    total:                           409712
transactions:                        25607  (426.73 per sec.)
deadlocks:                           0      (0.00 per sec.)
read/write requests:                 358498 (5974.23 per sec.)
other operations:                    51214  (853.46 per sec.)

Test execution summary:
total time:                          60.0074s
total number of events:              25607
total time taken by event execution: 479.9015
per-request statistics:
     min:                                  7.50ms
     avg:                                 18.74ms
     max:                                 48.85ms
     approx.  95 percentile:              21.88ms

Threads fairness:
events (avg/stddev):           3200.8750/5.73
execution time (avg/stddev):   59.9877/0.00
```

Comment: Sysbench is sensitive to network latency. For best results I would recommend running sysbench from a GCE VM and configure the Cloud SQL instance to follow that GCE zone. I would also recommend running the tests for longer (15-20 minutes), enable the reporting every 10 seconds and watch when performance is stabilizing.

Comment: Note: the current minimum latency for a `SELECT 1` from Google Compute Engine to a Cloud SQL instance is about 1-1.5ms.